# Symfony2 Form get data value in form type

Tags: php, forms, symfony, events

I want modify a form with a content value :
I try with "PRE_BIND" event but this doesn't work if the form isn't send a first time.
I have this :

```
<?php

namespace YOU\CommercantBundle\Form\Type;


use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class LivraisonChoixType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {


        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_BIND, function (FormEvent $event) use ($builder)
        {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            if ((int)$data['pays'] > 0) {

                $form->remove('livreur');
                $pays = $data['pays'];

                $form->add('livreur','entity',array(
                        'property' =>'name',
                        'class' => 'YOUAdminBundle:Livreur',
                        'label' => 'Livreur :',
                        'query_builder' => function($er) use ($pays){
                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                ->join('c.pays', 'p')
                                ->andWhere('p.id= :pays')
                                ->addOrderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
                                ->setParameter('pays', $pays);
                        },
                    )
            );

            }
        });

        $builder
            ->add('pays','pays',array('label'=>'Destination :'))
            ->add('livreur','entity',array(
                        'property' =>'name',
                        'class' => 'YOUAdminBundle:Livreur',
                        'label' => 'Livreur :',
                        'query_builder' => function($er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                            ->join('c.pays', 'p')
                            ->andWhere('p.id= :pays')
                            ->addOrderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
                            ->setParameter('pays', 0);
                    },
                )
            )
            ->add('prix','number',array('required'=>true,'label' => 'Frais :'))
            ->add('prix2','number',array('required'=>false,'label' => 'Frais en second article :'))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'YOU\CommercantBundle\Entity\LivraisonChoix',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'you_commercantbundle_livraisonchoixtype';
    }
}
```

Called by this form type :

```
<?php

namespace YOU\CommercantBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class LivraisonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name','text',array('required'=>true,'label'=>'Nom :'))
            ->add('choix','collection',array(
                            'type'=>new LivraisonChoixType(),
                            'options'=>array('attr'=>array('class'=>'livreur-collection')),
                            'allow_add' => true,
                            'allow_delete' => true,
                            'by_reference' => false,
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'YOU\CommercantBundle\Entity\Livraison'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'you_commercantbundle_livraisontype';
    }
}
```

Anyone know how I can get the value ?

Comment: what is the expected behavior of the form? user sees form, enters "pays", then submits, gets the same form with different choices? what are you doing in your controller?

Comment: the query need update parametter "pays" with the "pays" input value

Comment: what do you mean by "but this don't work if the form isn't send a first time." ? surely you have to send some request/submit the form before the fields can be updated right?

Comment: When i edit the content, the data is here, but the event is not used because, the form is not send ...

Comment: without a request there can be no update of the form ... it can't update itself. why don't you send the form via ajax ?

Comment: It's not a best method, the best is to have the form ok directly, i try with "PRE_SET_DATA" event, but the "$data = $event->getData();" method return a big objet 'livraisonChoix', but without the method for get data.

Comment: jeah it should be $form->getData() instead of $event->getData() :-)

Comment: this work on controller, but this don't work on the event, in form type.
I get "A cycle was detected. Listeners to the PRE_SET_DATA event must not call setData(). You should call setData() on the FormEvent object instead."

Comment: my french sucks a bit but "pays" is country right? and "livreur" is delivery guy/company right, "livraison" is delivery? so in your application one delivery can have multiple delivery-guys/-companies ( asking because of the collection )? Still one delivery can have multiple delivery-companies from multiple countries ? Now you want to filter delivery guys by country? Why do you use a number for the default country ( 0 )?

Comment: yes, i have a collection of country for any delivery compagny, and i want draw the correct list with the selected country.
I can do it after with ajax.
But when i open an existing old form for edit the value, the country is selected, and i want draw the correct select for delivery compagny, my query do it fine. But i need dynamicly give the country id to the query this the existing data in entity.

Comment: one delivery-company -> many countries ... or one country -> many delivery companies? What shall the user select ? a country first and then one of the companies in that country? ... btw i get the problem with the edit form

Comment: The user select a country, and a delivery compagny after.
The user can save the complete form and open it again after.
When the user open it again, the country is already selected. i need to get the country ID, for create the great delivery list.

Comment: Need to use PRE_SET_DATA :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319277/symfony2-pre-set-data-event-getdata-return-wrong-object

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer but this is what I do when I want to assign values to forms before they are rendered. Basically I would bind the form to an entity as such:

```
// First create entity that will bind with form
$someEntityInstance = new myEntity();
$someEntityInstance->setPropertyOne(5);
$someEntityInstance->setPropertyTwo('another value');

// Then bind entity to form
$myForm = $this->createForm(new myFormType, $someEntityInstance);
```

Any properties that are mapped from the form to the entity will have the same value and when rendered in the view, this will show up. Though if I have multiple entities represented in a form, I then create a new thing class called a processor that will have properties mapped and bound to the form that can also change the form field values.

This is the easiest way that I know for changing form field values before rendering them.