# Symfony2 form collection form events $data->getData() returns null

Tags: php, forms, collections, null

I have a form with a collection of forms in which I want to chain two drop boxes with an event.
   I do not manage to make the event listener to work as I get a null value when I call `$data->getCursValutar()`.
    Here is the code:

```
<?php

 namespace Mnv\CoreBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class ClientiType extends AbstractType
{



public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $idSocietate = $options['data']->getSocietati()->getIdSocietate();

   // var_dump($dateClienti);
    $builder->add('cod','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('denumire','text', array('required' => true));
    $builder->add('cod_fiscal','text', array('required' => true));
    $builder->add('cont_analitic','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('telefon','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('email','email', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('judet','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('adresa','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('nr_reg_comertului','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('cont','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('banca','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('delegat','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('delegat_serie_ci','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('delegat_nr_ci','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('delegat_ci_eliberat','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('delegat_mij_transport','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('agent','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('discount','text',array('required' => false));

    $builder->add('date_clienti', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new DateClientiType($idSocietate),
        'cascade_validation' => true,
        'prototype' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'required' => false,
        ));

    $builder->add('adauga','submit');



}


public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Mnv\CoreBundle\Entity\Clienti',
        'cascade_validation' => true,
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'form_clienti';
}
}
```

And the second form:

```
<?php


 namespace Mnv\CoreBundle\Form;

  use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

  use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
  use Mnv\CoreBundle\Entity\Orase;


  class DateClientiType extends AbstractType
  {

private $idSocietate;

function __construct($idSocietate) {
    $this->idSocietate = $idSocietate;

}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function ($event) {
        $event->stopPropagation();
     }, 900);


    $builder->add('suprafata_inchiriata','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('suma_chirie','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('suma_fixa_chirie','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('curs_bnr','checkbox', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('platitor_tva','checkbox', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('fact_auto','checkbox', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('nr_contract','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('data_contract','date', array('required' => false, 'widget' => 'single_text', 'format'=>'dd/MM/yyyy'));
    $builder->add('act_aditional','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('data_actaditional','date', array('required' => false, 'widget' => 'single_text', 'format'=>'dd/MM/yyyy'));
    $builder->add('strada_spatiu','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('etaj_spatiu','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('pozitie_spatiu','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('achitare','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('tip_fact_utilitati', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array( 
           'cumulata' => 'Cumulata',
           'unitara' => 'Unitara',
           'separata' => 'Separata'
            ),
        'required' => false,
        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => false,
        'invalid_message' => 'Valoarea aleasa nu este valida!',
        'empty_value' => false
    ));



   $builder->add('orase', 'entity', array(
            'class'       => 'MnvCoreBundle:Orase',
            'property'    => 'oras',
            'empty_value' => 'Selectati',
        ));


        $idSocietate = $this->idSocietate;
        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Orase $orase = null) use ($idSocietate) {
        $positions = array();
        if (null !== $orase) {
           $positions = $orase;
        }
        $form->add('cursuri', 'entity', array(
            'class'       => 'MnvCoreBundle:CursValutar',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($idSocietate,$positions) {        
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                     ->where('c.societati = :idSocietate AND c.orase = :oras')
                     ->setParameter('idSocietate', $idSocietate)
                     ->setParameter('oras', $positions)
                     ->orderBy('c.idCurs', 'ASC');
                },
            'empty_value' => 'Selectati',
        ));
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
            $data = $event->getData();

            var_dump($data); exit;

             $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getCursValutar());   


        }
    );

    $builder->get('orase')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
            // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
            $oras = $event->getForm()->getData();

            // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
            // the parent to the callback functions!
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $oras);
        }
    );


}


 public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Mnv\CoreBundle\Entity\DateClienti',
        'cascade_validation' => true,
    ));
}

 public function getName()
 {
     return 'date_clienti';
 }
}
```

I am new to symfony and I am doing a battle to learn it. What am I  doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was already answered here: [Symfony2 PRE_SET_DATA $event->getData() return wrong object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319277/symfony2-pre-set-data-event-getdata-return-wrong-object)
It was in the related question block.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I found the solution :) after 3 days of pain ):
It was simple, of course.

Read the comments:

```
   <?php


namespace Mnv\CoreBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Mnv\CoreBundle\Entity\Orase;
use Mnv\CoreBundle\Entity\DateClienti;


class DateClientiType extends AbstractType
{

    private $idSocietate;

    function __construct($idSocietate) {
        $this->idSocietate = $idSocietate;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function ($event) {
            $event->stopPropagation();
         }, 900);


        $builder->add('suprafata_inchiriata','text',array('required' => false));
        $builder->add('suma_chirie','text',array('required' => false));
        $builder->add('suma_fixa_chirie','text',array('required' => false));
        $builder->add('curs_bnr','checkbox', array('required' => false));
        $builder->add('platitor_tva','checkbox', array('required' => false));
        $builder->add('fact_auto','checkbox', array('required' => false));
        $builder->add('nr_contract','text',array('required' => false));
        $builder->add('data_contract','date', array('required' => false, 'widget' => 'single_text', 'format'=>'dd/MM/yyyy'));
        $builder->add('act_aditional','text',array('required' => false));
        $builder->add('data_actaditional','date', array('required' => false, 'widget' => 'single_text', 'format'=>'dd/MM/yyyy'));
        $builder->add('strada_spatiu','text',array('required' => false));
        $builder->add('etaj_spatiu','text',array('required' => false));
        $builder->add('pozitie_spatiu','text',array('required' => false));
        $builder->add('achitare','text',array('required' => false));
        $builder->add('tip_fact_utilitati', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array( 
               'cumulata' => 'Cumulata',
               'unitara' => 'Unitara',
               'separata' => 'Separata'
                ),
            'required' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
            'invalid_message' => 'Valoarea aleasa nu este valida!',
            'empty_value' => false
        ));



       $builder->add('orase', 'entity', array(
                'class'       => 'MnvCoreBundle:Orase',
                'property'    => 'oras',
                'empty_value' => 'Selectati',
            ));


            $idSocietate = $this->idSocietate;
            $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Orase $orase = null) use ($idSocietate) {
            $positions = array();
            if (null !== $orase) {
               $positions = $orase;
            }
            $form->add('curs_valutar', 'entity', array(
                'class'       => 'MnvCoreBundle:CursValutar',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($idSocietate,$positions) {        
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                         ->where('c.societati = :idSocietate AND c.orase = :oras')
                         ->setParameter('idSocietate', $idSocietate)
                         ->setParameter('oras', $positions)
                         ->orderBy('c.idCurs', 'ASC');
                    },
                'empty_value' => 'Selectati',
            ));
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                $data = $event->getData();

                //var_dump($data); exit;
                // so after var dumping i noticed the $data was null
                // i tried many solutions found online with no success
                // so the problem was the error i got when getOrase was called on a non
                // object, so i need it an object and here it is:

                if ($data !== null) { // chack to see if $data is not null
                    // now we can safely call getOrase() on event
                   $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getOrase()); 
                } else { // if it is null
                    $data = new DateClienti; // instantiate the class 
                                             // (don't forget to import the class)
                    $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getOrase()); // no error now :)
                }



            }
        );

        $builder->get('orase')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
                // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
                $oras = $event->getForm()->getData();

                // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
                // the parent to the callback functions!
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $oras);
            }
        );


    }


    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Mnv\CoreBundle\Entity\DateClienti',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'date_clienti';
    }
   }
```